# How would i append two lists already on a txt file?

Tags: python, list

I want to be able to create two lists: Time and data.

```
import time
date = [time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M%p")]
data = []
x = input()
data.append(x)
with open("RapData.txt", "a") as output:
    output.write(str(date))
    output.write(str(data))
```

This code makes the two lists and saves it all on one line in the txt file like this if ran twice:

```
['2017/06/28 02:15PM']['x']['2017/06/28 02:15PM']['x']
```

and i want it to be:

```
['2017/06/28 02:15PM']['2017/06/28 02:15PM']
['x']['x']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the newline character to the file as well:

```
import time
date = [time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M%p")]

f = open("RapData.txt", "a")

data = [input()]

f.write(str(date))
f.write('\n')
f.write(str(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking for you can't use append (as append adds items to the end of the file).

You would need to read the data to a local variable and output it to the file again:

```
open("RapData.txt","r")
... read code...

open("RapData.txt","w")
... write code..
```